# How to use different external style sheet every time a jquery plugin function is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

i'm using a `jQuery plugin` that I wrote a while ago; It is a grid view plugin. I'm trying to use this plugin twice on the same page, with two different `div`s

The plugin is using an `External Style sheet`

I need to use a specific External style sheet with each of the gridviews plugin

The page loops through the div array, and calls the `gridview()` function which creates the grid view

```
var divs = ['div1', 'div2'];
//At this point how can i tell it which external style sheet it can use?
 for(var i in divs){ 
        $('#' + divs[i]).gridView({}) ;
```

like in this example :

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/2TL2K/2/)

I have tried doing this

```
condition ? $('head').append('link to 1st sheet') :
            $('head').append('link to 2st sheet')
```

and this always gives me the `2nd style sheet`

Comment: Actually using that fiddle, both stylesheets are being loaded.  But if they don't have different selectors then the second one will override the first one no matter what.

Comment: @Deryck i don't have a different selector the css is a class selector

Comment: Give div1 an id of #div1 and div2 gets #div2.  Then go into stylesheet 1 and place #div1 in front of everything (or in the proper position relating to the other selectors), and do the same to sheet 2

Comment: @Deryck unfortunately the divs are dynamic :) there must be a more generic way of doing this

Comment: There is.  Add classes instead.  Or do it through Javascript to add the classes if you can't through HTML.  As it is now, your selectors are overwriting each other so this is the only way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a class at runtime to each list, then add those classes to all distinct elements in the CSS.

```
var divs = ['div1', 'div2'];
//At this point how can i tell it which external style sheet it can use?
 for(var i in divs){ 
        $('#' + divs[i]).addClass('style'+i).gridView({}) ;
```

then add style+i to all your distinct styles

```
.style1 .hideDateTimePicker{height:1000px}
.style1 .headerTitle {width:50%;float: left;height:25px;padding-left:10px;padding-top:5px} /*div*/ 
.style1 .headerTitle span {height:24px;padding:1px;padding-right:5px;padding-left:5px;position:relative;font-size:100%;color:#3a3a3a;font-weight:bold;}
```

and so on. I would recommend using [scss](http://sass-lang.com/) to make that addition of css way easier.